# How do I measure the efficiency of reading and writing in a written language?

Tags: written-language

How do I standardize a comparison between the efficiency of reading and writing in from one written language to another?

An example of what I mean would be words-typed-per-minute in a given language standardized to a norm within typist for that language.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? I'm not sure I got what you're asking...

Comment: By efficiency in writing, do you mean average transcription speeds measured in morphemes transcribed per second?   By efficiency in reading, do you mean the greatest speed with the greatest comprehension?  I don't know, I'm just guessing.  I assume you're talking about averages over a sample population of literate speakers of at least 100 for each language.  Looking forward to your elaboration.

Comment: I'd start by finding out how many writing systems can be typed.

Comment: By the way, please add the elaborations in your question... Re-word it so that it's clear for new visitors (even if they ignore the comments).

Comment: @James Grossmann: Yes, both transcription and comprehension. [Flesch–Kincaid readability test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_test) and [Gunning fog index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunning_fog_index) would be example of indexing [readability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readability), but to my knowledge there meant to be used within English, and not sure how you'd compare languages. Does that help, or confuse the questions intent more? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you'll need instruments that compare comprehension vs. speed and morphemes per second transcription rates across languages.  Are there such?

Comment: @James Grossmann: Don't believe instruments are really required, other than a stop watch and an audio recorder, since to really compare languages the concepts presented would have to be "universal expressions". What sort of instruments were you thinking of?

Comment: @ blunders:  Standardized tests.

Comment: This paper applies to speech, but might give you some ideas on variation and standards: http://lsadc.org/info/documents/2011/press-releases/pellegrino-et-al.pdf

Comment: +1 @Arkadiy Kukarkin: Thank you for pointing out the paper, and I agree the paper is relevant to the topic, and very interesting to see the results of the research too. Please post the paper as an answer, and I will select it as the answer. It might also be of use to know how you knew about the paper, or went about finding it; meaning knowing that might make it easier for me to find more information on my own. Again, thanks!